# Can deleted projects be automatically removed from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, m2eclipse, m2e

I recently deleted an old Maven Module (= Eclipse project) and created a new one in its place. The updates were then pushed into Git.

Everyone on the team is using Eclipse and pulling the update from Git doesn't remove the old project from Eclipse automatically. Is there any way of forcing this to happen or does everyone have to manually remove old projects from Eclipse (followed by Maven -> Import Project to get the new one)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the deletes weren't committed and only the inserts/updates were committed.  Check your workspace for uncommitted changes and then confirm that those changes made it to git (Github and Bitbucket will let you view the commit history for a repo or you can use the git log command if you're sharing a repo internally).

Comment: Thanks but the deletes were committed - the issue is with Eclipse not about it when you've previously added the projects via Import - Maven Project.